# Show full product title into Woocommerce Shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

this is my first time here, and have one issue that i need help to resolve. I use Woocommerece 3.4.2 and have issue with it. I want to show full product title into woocommerce shop page. Currently its striping with `...` at end. I want to show in two rows for example.

For [Example](http://www.bevelini.com/shop/page/3/)

[image from issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaV7Q.png)

I tryed to fix with CSS, using this:

```
.woocommerce .archive-products ul.products .tb-product-items .tb-product-item 
.tb-product-item-inner .tb-content .tb-title a {
display:inline-flex;
 }
```

but resolved the issue just temporary. Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by temporary resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `text-ellipsis` class applied to anchor or else remove this CSS property

```
.text-ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class 'text-ellipsis' from the DIV surrounding anchor - that's it!